# cmake: how to link a library which has a lib prefix on windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cmake

On GNU/Linux the convention is to pass the name of the library (let's call it foo) to target_link_libraries without the lib prefix (otherwise it tries to link liblibfoo.so). On windows however when I'm asking to link with "foo" it tries to find "foo.lib" which does not exist, as the library is named libfoo.lib. Is there a way to instruct cmake to add the lib prefix, without resorting to yet another if(WIN32) block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_library.html) for search absolute path to the library. You may specify all possible names of searched library with `NAMES` option:

```
find_library(FOO_LIBRARY NAMES foo libfoo)
```

Then use result of this command for link with the library:

```
target_link_libraries(my_exec ${FOO_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: No, I'm talking about libraries without cmake modules.

Comment: There is no CMake modules involved. Command `find_library` is internal for CMake, like `target_link_libraries` itself.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood. I thought you said find_package for some reason. I didn't know about find_library, which indeed finds the library. However I don't like that it links it with full absolute path, so I think I'll stick with the conditional for now.

Comment: If you bother about absolute path to the library being used in RPATH for the binary created, then this is done by CMake only *by default*. Using CMake variables and properties you may adjust RPATH to the value which you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.